# HTTP request POST in a esp8266 without body

Tags: arduino, httprequest, esp8266

I am getting HTTP Error code 411 while posting an HTTP request over esp8266. The request must be chunked or have a content length, but my http request doesn't have a body. What can i do to post it?

```
 Serial.print("Requesting POST: ");
client.println("POST /communitysafeapi/Alert/1/1/0 HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: camilledata.cloudapp.net");
client.println("Accept: */*");
client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
//client.print("Content-Length: ");
//client.println(content.length());
client.println();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using HTTP post request without body is not a preferred way but it is ok.

From IETF draft [document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-11#page-17):

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the
> representation enclosed in the request as data to be processed by the
> target resource.

You would add this to your header to avoid 411 error for your case:

```
Content-Length: 0
```

OR would use an HTTP GET request instead of a post if would like to trigger some state on the server side.

Comment: I've tried before but i don't get answer from the server

Comment: I got this : HTTP Error 400. There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue adding it to this way

```
client.println("Content-Length: "+String(0)+"");
```

Comment: aka `client.println("Content-Length: 0");` (no need to template)